# Publishing Shapefile to WMSbwith FME

Tags: wms, fme-flow

I'm using FME Desktop and Server 2014.
At the moment my workspace looks like the following. It reads a .csv file and transforms this to a ESRi Shapefile. This is working. I can use the shapefile with QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

The next step, which I want to perform:
Create a WMS Service Link, which uses my FME or ArcGIS Server.
Because FME provides the functionality to publish the workspace as an OGC Web map Service, I would assume that this works.

[image]

I've already tried to publish the workspace as shown in the first pic. The WMS Service is up and running and I can load the WMS Service to ArcMap, I can query the WMS link and the layer is shown. Unfortunately when I want to add the layer to the map, I get the error **"A selected item could not be added to the map. Could not connect to server".**

So my first question: Is there any error with my workspace?
Second "question": If searched for some solutions and I found that I need to have a result as [PNG, JPEG, TIF](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Server_Documentation/Default.htm#web_services/ogc_web_mapping_service.htm).
So my question would be: What do I need to add/edit in my workspace to get my idea to work?

Comment: Have you tried WFS as well as WMS - see related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15742/should-i-use-wfs-wms-or-sos-considering-performance-and-security

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is because you're writing to an Esri Shape file. That would work for WFS, but not for WMS, which is a raster format.

So, yes. Use Writers > Add Writer to add a raster format such as PNG. But, you'll also need to convert the data coming out of the 2DPointAdder to raster, which you would do with an ImageRasterizer transformer.

Answer (score -1):

So WMS is a raster based output solution. If I were working on this, I would want to use the mapnik tool to control the graphic output.

**WMS with FME**

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Spatial-Image-Serving-Through-WMS-with-FME-Server#heading_toc_j_4

**Mapnick with FME**

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Introduction-to-MapnikRasterizer